# Higher derivative of cross-entropy loss?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, cross-entropy

Has anyone worked out a formula for the higher derivatives of cross-entropy loss $J(z)$ with $z$ referring to logits? Loss is defined as follows:

$$J(p(z)) = -\sum_i q_i\log p(z)_i$$
$$p(z)_i=\frac{\exp z_i}{\sum_i \exp z_i}$$

Lower-order level derivatives have nice forms

- First $H_1=p-q$
- [Second](https://yaroslavvb.medium.com/using-evolved-notation-to-derive-the-hessian-of-cross-entropy-loss-195f8c7b3a92) $H_2=\text{diag}(p)-pp'$
- Second has symmetric factorization: $H_2=Q^TQ$ with $Q=\text{diag}(\sqrt{p})-\sqrt{p}p'$

I need a formula for higher derivatives, ideally with a decomposition analogous to $H_2=Q^T Q$

I'm guessing there's a nice formula because numeric values [seem nice](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/symmetric-softmax-decomposition.nb). For instance, substituting $z=(1,1,1)$, I get the following value for the third derivative:

$$H_3=\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 \frac{2}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} \\
 -\frac{1}{27} & -\frac{1}{27} & \frac{2}{27} \\
\end{array}\right)
\right]$$